# Error when deploying Angular app to Heroku

Tags: angular, heroku

I am trying to deplpy an angular app to heroku, and in the error

```
ERROR in src/app/components/user-sidebar/sidebar.component.html(31,66): : Property 'isAdmin' does not exist on type 'SidebarComponent'.
```

But `isAdmin` isn't supposed to be a field on the `SidebarComponent`.  It used to be, when I first wrote it, but then I refactored and removed it.  In fact, in the github repo my app which heroku is pulling from, I never committed that version of the code, so I don't know why it's complaining about that field being missing.

I have previously deployed apps to heroku before.  Here is the full build log and some of my files:

FYI, the `engines` in package.json are correct.  Those are the versions of npm and node I have installed on my machine.

Heroku Build Logs

```
-----> Node.js app detected

-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false

-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  10.16.0
       engines.npm (package.json):   6.9.0

       Resolving node version 10.16.0...
       Downloading and installing node 10.16.0...
       npm 6.9.0 already installed with node

-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)

       > kroe761-app@2.3.0 preinstall /tmp/build_dfa881318ac3ca0a1cb6d9eb58e6e0d6
       > npm install -g @angular/cli

       /tmp/build_dfa881318ac3ca0a1cb6d9eb58e6e0d6/.heroku/node/bin/ng -> /tmp/build_dfa881318ac3ca0a1cb6d9eb58e6e0d6/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng

       > @angular/cli@8.1.2 postinstall /tmp/build_dfa881318ac3ca0a1cb6d9eb58e6e0d6/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
       > node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

       + @angular/cli@8.1.2
       added 239 packages from 185 contributors in 11.552s

       > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_dfa881318ac3ca0a1cb6d9eb58e6e0d6/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
       > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"


       > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_dfa881318ac3ca0a1cb6d9eb58e6e0d6/node_modules/karma/node_modules/core-js
       > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"


       > @angular/cli@8.0.3 postinstall /tmp/build_dfa881318ac3ca0a1cb6d9eb58e6e0d6/node_modules/@angular/cli
       > node ./bin/postinstall/script.js


       > chartist@0.11.2 postinstall /tmp/build_dfa881318ac3ca0a1cb6d9eb58e6e0d6/node_modules/chartist

       > core-js@3.1.3 postinstall /tmp/build_dfa881318ac3ca0a1cb6d9eb58e6e0d6/node_modules/core-js
       > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"


       > kroe761-app@2.3.0 postinstall /tmp/build_dfa881318ac3ca0a1cb6d9eb58e6e0d6
       > ng build --aot --prod


       Date: 2019-07-20T02:50:34.441Z
       Hash: cd983ec987dacf80900e
       Time: 42210ms
       chunk {0} runtime.741402d1d47331ce975c.js (runtime) 1.41 kB [entry] [rendered]
       chunk {1} main.4af9b61479361f268d39.js (main) 128 bytes [initial] [rendered]
       chunk {2} polyfills.d64fff5b0a45205ed7b5.js (polyfills) 130 bytes [initial] [rendered]
       chunk {3} polyfills-es5.613d1909ec381c0aefb7.js (polyfills-es5) 68 kB [initial] [rendered]
       chunk {4} styles.02d35618b7ff5627c133.css (styles) 583 kB [initial] [rendered]
       chunk {scripts} scripts.23c891176a6fdb868027.js (scripts) 304 kB [entry] [rendered]

       ERROR in src/app/components/user-sidebar/sidebar.component.html(31,66): : Property 'isAdmin' does not exist on type 'SidebarComponent'.

       npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
       npm ERR! errno 1
       npm ERR! kroe761-app@2.3.0 postinstall: `ng build --aot --prod`
       npm ERR! Exit status 1
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Failed at the kroe761-app@2.3.0 postinstall script.
       npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.ZUiIp/_logs/2019-07-20T02_50_34_594Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed

       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/

       Love,
       Heroku

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
Build finished
heroku.com
Blogs
Careers
Documentation
Support
Terms of Service
Privacy
Cookies
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "kroe761-app",
    "version": "2.3.0",
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "node server.js",
        "build": "ng build --prod",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e",
        "install:clean": "rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && ng serve -o",
        "preinstall": "npm install -g @angular/cli",
        "postinstall": "ng build --aot --prod"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": "10.16.0",
        "npm": "6.9.0"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.6",
        "@angular/animations": "8.0.0",
        "@angular/cdk": "8.0.1",
        "@angular/common": "8.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "8.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "8.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "8.0.0",
        "@angular/material": "8.0.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "8.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-server": "8.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "8.0.0",
        "ajv": "6.10.0",
        "arrive": "2.4.1",
        "bootstrap": "4.3.1",
        "bootstrap-material-design": "4.1.2",
        "bootstrap-notify": "3.1.3",
        "chartist": "0.11.2",
        "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
        "core-js": "3.1.3",
        "express": "4.17.1",
        "googleapis": "40.0.0",
        "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
        "jquery": "3.4.1",
        "moment": "2.24.0",
        "perfect-scrollbar": "1.1.0",
        "popper.js": "1.15.0",
        "rxjs": "6.5.2",
        "rxjs-compat": "6.5.2",
        "web-animations-js": "2.3.1",
        "zone.js": "0.9.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.800.2",
        "@angular/cli": "8.0.3",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.0.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "8.0.0",
        "@types/bootstrap": "4.3.0",
        "@types/chartist": "0.9.46",
        "@types/googlemaps": "3.36.4",
        "@types/jasmine": "3.3.13",
        "@types/jquery": "3.3.29",
        "@types/node": "12.0.7",
        "codelyzer": "5.1.0",
        "jasmine-core": "3.4.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
        "karma": "4.1.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
        "karma-cli": "2.0.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.0.5",
        "karma-jasmine": "2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.4.2",
        "protractor": "5.4.2",
        "ts-node": "8.2.0",
        "tslint": "5.17.0",
        "typescript": "3.4.5"
    }
}
```

angular.json

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
        "kroe761-app": {
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src",
            "projectType": "application",
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "options": {
                        "outputPath": "dist/kroe761-app",
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "main": "src/main.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "assets": [
                            "src/assets",
                            "src/favicon.ico"
                        ],
                        "styles": [
                            "node_modules/perfect-scrollbar/css/perfect-scrollbar.css",
                            "src/assets/scss/material-dashboard.scss",
                            "src/assets/css/demo.css"
                        ],
                        "scripts": [
                            "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
                            "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
                            "node_modules/bootstrap-material-design/dist/js/bootstrap-material-design.min.js",
                            "node_modules/arrive/src/arrive.js",
                            "node_modules/moment/moment.js",
                            "node_modules/perfect-scrollbar/dist/perfect-scrollbar.min.js",
                            "node_modules/bootstrap-notify/bootstrap-notify.js",
                            "node_modules/chartist/dist/chartist.js"
                        ]
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "optimization": true,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "extractCss": true,
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "aot": true,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "vendorChunk": false,
                            "buildOptimizer": true,
                            "fileReplacements": [
                                {
                                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                    "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "serve": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "kroe761-app:build"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "browserTarget": "kroe761-app:build:production"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "extract-i18n": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "kroe761-app:build"
                    }
                },
                "test": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
                    "options": {
                        "main": "src/test.ts",
                        "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
                        "scripts": [
                            "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
                            "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
                            "node_modules/bootstrap-material-design/dist/js/bootstrap-material-design.min.js",
                            "node_modules/arrive/src/arrive.js",
                            "node_modules/moment/moment.js",
                            "node_modules/perfect-scrollbar/dist/perfect-scrollbar.min.js",
                            "node_modules/bootstrap-notify/bootstrap-notify.js",
                            "node_modules/chartist/dist/chartist.js"
                        ],
                        "styles": [
                            "node_modules/perfect-scrollbar/css/perfect-scrollbar.css",
                            "src/assets/scss/material-dashboard.scss",
                            "src/assets/css/demo.css"
                        ],
                        "assets": [
                            "src/assets",
                            "src/favicon.ico"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "lint": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": [
                            "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                            "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
                        ],
                        "exclude": []
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "kroe761-app-e2e": {
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "",
            "projectType": "application",
            "architect": {
                "e2e": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
                    "options": {
                        "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
                        "devServerTarget": "kroe761-app:serve"
                    }
                },
                "lint": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": [
                            "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
                        ],
                        "exclude": []
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "defaultProject": "kroe761-app",
    "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
            "prefix": "app",
            "styleext": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:directive": {
            "prefix": "app"
        }
    }
}
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/kroe761-app'));
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/kroe761-app/index.html'));
});
```

Comment: Mind you share your code in github with me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.....I'm an idiot.  I'll keep this up in case someone else can learn from my stupidity.  I left a reference to `isAdmin` in the sidebar template as `*ngIf="!isAdmin"`.  Because it was false VS Code Intellisense didn't flag it.

Whoops.

Comment: ‍♂️ It is what it is I suppose!